# SharePoint 2013 always creates new elements in top level folder of Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a problem with SharePoint 2013. I'm currently setting up a basic collaboration sceanario with SharePoint. I therefore created a basic document Library whith an additional folder derived content type to be used at the top level of the document library. This content type has some additional metadata. Inside of these specialized folders I want to use standard files and (sub)folders.

At first, I had no problem of creating elements and subfolders inside of my top level folders using the standard buttons (Upload File, New Folder) in the ribbon. However, now without knowing what caused this behaviour, when I try to create elements inside of existing folders, SharePoint always creates new elements at the top level of the document library.

Does somebody have an idea what might have caused this beaviour and how to fix it (without code)? I did not find any solution searching the web. Any Help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

P.S. I know that using folders in SharePoint is not recommended in general but I would really like to understand what could have caused the described problem.

Comment: If you don't get any help here, you might want to try http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hey DeanOC, thanks for the hint.